# DateTime.Today in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to return a view which will display the logs from current day.

This sql query does exactly what i need:

```
select * from Logs where Date>=GETDATE()-1
```

but I am having trouble with the razor syntax to write this statement in my view.

```
return View(db.Logs.Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Today()-1));
```

Any idea how to display logs in the view for the current date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is either:

```
return View(db.Logs.Where(a => a.Date == DateTime.Today));
```

or, if you want to substract one day:

```
return View(db.Logs.Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)));
```

Please note, that DateTime is a struct and `Now`, `Today` or `Date` are properties, not methods, so you can not call them like method (`DateTime.Today()`).
They are called just like any other property, without the paranthesis.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Off-Topic:

> I have tried this one but it doesn't work.

Is a bad phrasing here on SO. People tend to react allergic to this, as it does not state, what excatly is wrong. Do you get unexpected results, exceptions, compiler-warnings etc. In your case it was fairly simple, because you were dealing with some syntactic mistakes, but in a more complex scenario, this will not go well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! and thanks for the off-topic reminder, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get logs from the current day, do you mean from midnight of the current day until now, or the past 24 hours.

Your original query in SQL using `GETDATE()` is equivelent to `DateTime.Now`, not `DateTime.Today`

As Serv has mentioned, what exactly is the results that you're getting that are incorrect? My suggestions for duplicating what you're seeing from your sql query would be this:

```
return View(db.Logs.Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
```

If you want it to display for the current date since midnight, use this:

```
return View(db.Logs.Where(a => a.Date >= DateTime.Today));
```

*But might I also make an additional suggestion, do not return your entity objects directly to the view, map them over to a view model object and send that to your view with **ONLY** the data that you need from your entity (even if it includes all the fields)*

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Both your suggestions worked for me!